# How to display the last value in Grafana Gauge

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, gauge

I'm new to using Grafana and I'm trying to display the last value of a table that's organized by dates in a Gauge visualization.
All the options I'm seeing to displaying the data are grouping methods like max, average, sum and so on.
Is there a way to get only the latest most updated value from that table? And to always display it?
I'm using Grafana v7.1.3 and ES.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose "Last" or "Last (not null)" from the "Display" option:

[image: Grafana display configuration]